# Ubuntu 22.04.2 on Macbook Pro 17 (late 2011) - unable to get builtin display to native 1920x1200 resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, macbook

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my Macbook Pro 17 (late 2011). It worked right out of the box including my wireless drivers! Running Ubuntu on this laptop definitely breathes new life into a aging but still very capable laptop!

The only issue I've seen is that the builtin display resolution isn't what it should be. Natively, the resolution this display is 1920x1200 (per spec), yet the best I can get is 1440x900 in Ubuntu.

I've already tried using cvt / xrandr / Xorg to add a new mode, but that seems to push the desktop larger than the viewable area.

details of what I've tried so far:

```
# xrandr - monitor name LVDS-1

cvt 1920 1200
 1920x1200 59.88 Hz (CVT 2.30MA) hsync: 74.56 kHz; pclk: 193.25 MHz
 Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200" 193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LVDS-1 1920x1200
# these settings push the screen resolution larger than the viewable area and it becomes completely unresponsive. Setting it through the Settings panel reverts it after 15 seconds
 

# cvt -r 1920 1200
# 1920x1200 59.95 Hz (CVT 2.30MA-R) hsync: 74.04 kHz; pclk: 154.00 MHz
# Modeline "1920x1200R"  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync
# xrandr --newmode "1920x1200R"  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync
# xrandr --addmode LVDS-1 1920x1200R
# just adding this mode (without setting it causes the system to freeze)


#information about graphics cards
lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760]
```

Has anyone else seen this issue, and more importantly, know how to fix it to get the true resolution of this display? (I won't mention how long I messed with this while using Wayland...)

I continue to search online for a solution but nothing has materialized yet.

UPDATE: I know this is just a setting somewhere. When checking out the Fractional Scaling options for the display, upon changing it to something other than 100%, the display briefly shifts to the proper mode, but then immediately expands to the selected scale (larger).